# Textbox lost focus event in MVC.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC project and I am having few issues with textbox lost focus event.
First I have a form there are four textboxes field, on first text box we need to pass name of the employee but we have called this textbox lost focus event to populate all records of Employee if it is already in the database but I am having problem when I pass name in the textbox and clicking "save" button then first textbox event called to check if record exist in the database or not then I need to reclick button once again to save my records if not exist.
So in that case I have to click button twice.

Please help with your thoughts I do not want user to click twice.

Thanks

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to help you without any code to review? MVC is a server side framework and does not set the focus of textboxes. That is performed using Javascript.

Comment: I understand John, code will be simple as I said earlier I am calling Lost focus event. There is noting new to show our developers team..Just wanted to have good thoughts on it as I am new bie.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you may use Jquery ajax to do the work. 
When the textbox focus is lost, an ajax get call will be made to the controller action which will check the DB and will return the status whether the username already exist or not.

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("#UserName").focusout(function () {
    var username = $("#UserName").val();
    var fullurl = '/User/UserNameCheck?username=' + username;
    if (username.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: fullurl,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            //data: username,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'UserNotPresent') {
                    $("#username_NotPresent_lbl").show();
                }
                else if (data == 'UserPresent') {
                    $("#username_Present_lbl").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#failed_check_lbl").show();
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#failed_check_lbl").show();
            }
        });
    }
});

$("#UserName").focus(function () {
    $("#username_NotPresent_lbl").hide();
    $("#username_Present_lbl").hide();
    $('#failed_check_lbl').hide();
}); });
```

Controller Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult UserNameCheck(string username)
    {            
        Users loggedInUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);
        if (loggedInUser != null)
        {
            return Json("UserPresent", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("UserNotPresent", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.Label("Sorry this user name is already in use", new {id="username_Present_lbl", @class ="ErrorLbl"})
            @Html.Label("User name available for use", new {id="username_NotPresent_lbl", @class ="SuccesLbl"})
            @Html.Label("Failed to validate the user name", new {id="failed_check_lbl", @class ="FailedCheckLbl"})                
        </div>
    </div>
```